# Laravel nova - login only for active user - disable login for inactive user

Tags: laravel-nova

using [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/), I want to disable inactive user from login,
and logout the user if already logged in,

i"m having a boolean column: "active" in users table.

if possible to show a message "only active users allowed to login" to inactive user

in the answer please specify exactly which file to edit and its path